# How to 'fit' the cells of UICollectionView FlowLayout?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, flowlayout, mosaic

My aim is to create an UICollectionView with different cell sizes and all cells **"fit in"**. There should be no empty place around the cells.

Here is an image of my Demo Application: [image]

The **sizes of t he Cells** are quarter, quaver and semiquaver **(1/4, 1/8 and 1/16)**. 
So how can i realize that? How can i delete the white space around the cells to push them all together to get a look like mosaic?

thanks for your help,
brush51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at RFQuiltLayout https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout it is exactly what you need.

[image: RFQuiltLayout fit]